Calculating F_IS, F_IT on ancient DNA
I am trying to calculate genetic diversity within a handful of ancient communities. I have 1240K genotype data (made pseudohaploid), and I need to generate statistics to estimate the levels of genetic diversity within these populations.
I was looking at F_IS and F_IT. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to calculate these on pseudohaploid aDNA. I have the data in Plink format.
